# Sigma algebra generated by an absolute value random variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

I need to find out what the sigma algebra generated by $Y$ looks like for $$Y: [0,1] \ni (\omega) \to 1- |2\omega -1| \in \mathbb{R}.$$

The graph of $Y$ is symmetric with respect to $\omega = \frac{1}{2}$.

I know the sigma algebra won't be all borel sets on $[0,1]$, because of the symmetry.

$Y^{-1}([a,b]) = [\frac{2-b}{2},\frac{2-a}{2} ] \cup [\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{2}]$

This is as far as I got. Could this help me determine what $\sigma(Y)$ is?

**EDIT:**

If we change the domain of Y so that $$Y: [0,2] \ni (\omega) \to 1- |2\omega -1| \in \mathbb{R}.$$

will then $$\sigma(Y) = \{A \subset [0,1] : A \ \text{is a borel set and} \ \forall x \in A: \frac{1}{2} -x \in A \} \cup \mathcal{B}[1,2]?$$ (point in $[1,2]$ have no common values with those in $[0,1]$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the $\sigma$-algebra $$\mathcal{F}=\left\{A\subseteq [0,1]:A\text{ is a borel set }\wedge\left(\forall x\in A,\ {1\over 2}-x\in A\right)\right\}$$

The easy part is showing that $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\mathcal{F}$.

As for the harder part, let $B\in\mathcal{F}$ a borel subset symmetrical with respect to ${1\over2}$. You can show that $Y(B)$ is a borel subset and that $Y^{-1}(Y(B))=B$.

**Hint**: $Y(B)=Y\left(B\cap\left[{1\over2},1\right]\right)$ and $Y|_{\left[{1\over2},1\right]}$ is the map $(x\mapsto 2-2x)$

**Added**:

The statement in the second part is false, substantially because the domain is not symmetrical with respect to ${1\over 2}$.

In that case, applying (again) the definition quoted in the other answer:

$$\sigma(Y)=\mathcal{F}':=\left\{A\subseteq [0,2]:A\text{ is a borel set }\wedge\forall x\in A\left({1\over2}-x\in A\vee{1\over2}-x\notin [0,2]\right)\right\}=\\=\left\{A\subseteq [0,2]:A\text{ is a borel set }\wedge\left(\forall x\in A\cap[0,1],\ {1\over2}-x\in A\right)\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you. How can I show that $Y(B)$ is measurable? It's not that obvious to me. After all, continuous image of a measurable set needs not be measurable. It is however true for a linear image. And we are dealing here with a linear map on $[0,1/2]$ and another linear map on $[1/2,1]$

Comment: $Y^{-1}(Y(B))=B$ is true, because $Y$ is surjective,  is that right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. If you want to be that general, the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ are saturated with respect to the function $Y$, which means that they satisfy $Y^{-1}(Y(B))=B$. But you can (and somehow you *must*) show it elementarily, using the fact that $$Y(x_1)=Y(x_2)\leftrightarrow \left(x_1=x_2\vee x_2={1\over2}-x_1\right)$$

Comment: So when it comes to proving that $Y(B)$ I need to use the fact that Y is linear on $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$. That is correct? But I still do not know how to use the equivalence above to prove that $Y^{-1}(B)=B$. Could you give me some more hints?

Comment: I've just noticed I made a typo in my comment above - there should be $Y^{-1}(Y(B))$. When it comes to $B=[a,b]$, we know that $Y(B)= [2-2b, 2-2a]$, and if the graph does not break at any point inside $[a,b]$, then we can safely say that $Y^{-1}(Y(B))=[a,b]$. And if $1/2 \in [a,b]$ we need to use the equivalence and we get that the preimage is $[a,b] \cup [1/2-b, 1/2-a]$. Is that right?

Comment: Well, yes. You can do the same for $B$ borel set. Notice that, if $B$ in $\mathcal{F}$, then $$B=\left\{x: x\in B\cap\left[{1\over2},1\right]\vee{1\over2}-x\in B\cap\left[{1\over2},1\right]\right\}$$, and that $Y|_{\left[{1\over2},1\right]}$ is injective...

Comment: Thank you. What about my edit to the question? Is my interpretation of sigma algebra for $Y: [0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ correct?

Comment: See my edit, @Bilbo

Comment: So if we have any borel set $B \subset [0,1]$, then $Y(B) \subset [0,1]$ is another borel set. And again, if $1/2 \not\in B$, then easily $Y^{-1}(Y(B)) = B$. If $1/2 \in B$, then the preimage is $B \cup 1/2 -B$, but due to the  representation of $B$ in your comment above, we note that  that set is in fact equal to $B$. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for your edit! Could you explain to me how to justify this alternative? $\forall x\in A\left({1\over2}-x\in A\vee{1\over2}-x\notin [0,2]\right)$

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{B}_{\left[0,1\right]}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra
on $\left[0,1\right]$ then $$\sigma\left(Y\right)=\left\{ Y^{-1}\left(B\right)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}_{\left[0,1\right]}\right\}$$

Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1063476/75923)