# Problem about not intersection stable generators

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Disprove: Let $(\Omega_1,\cal F_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\cal F_2)$ measure spaces and let $\cal D_1$ ,$\cal D_2$ generators of $\cal F_1$, $\cal F_2$ respectively, then $\cal D:=\{A \times B \mid A \in D_1, B \in D_2\}$ generates $\cal F_1 \otimes \cal F_2$.

I think if $\cal D_1$ and $\cal D_2$ are intersection stable , then this statement is true. But whithout this condition?

A counter example is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a general rule:

If $f:X\to Y$ and $\mathcal B\subseteq\wp(Y)$  then $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal B))=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal B))$.

Here $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ is a notation for the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal B$ as a subcollection.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1063526/75923) for a proof of that rule.

---

$\cal F_1 \otimes \cal F_2$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that the projections $\pi_i:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\to\Omega_i$ are both measurable.

Note that $\pi_i^{-1}(\mathcal D_i)\subseteq\mathcal D$ for $i=1,2$.

Then with the rule we find for $i=1,2$: $$\pi_i^{-1}(\mathcal F_i)=\pi_i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal D_i))=\sigma(\pi_i^{-1}(\mathcal D_i))\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal D)$$

So the functions $\pi_i$ are both measurable wrt $\mathcal\sigma(D)$ which means that $\cal F_1 \otimes \cal F_2\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal D)$.

Further it is evident that $\mathcal D\subseteq\cal F_1 \otimes \cal F_2$ so that also $\sigma(\mathcal D)\subseteq\cal F_1 \otimes \cal F_2$.

Proved is now:$$\sigma(\mathcal D)=\cal F_1 \otimes \cal F_2$$

Comment: thank you for help, so it is not neccessary that $D_1$and$D_2$ are intersection stable?

Comment: Indeed. That is not necessary.

Comment: is it formally possible to say $\pi_i^{-1}(\cal F_i) \in \sigma(\cal D)$?

Comment: No. It concerns a subcollection. Not an   element.